# Polymer core-ajax xml response element is null

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, polymer, web-component

I am trying to use Polymer core-ajax element to extract data out of an online API. Checking via developer tool the API request get successful with code 200 and expected XML response is returned. But the response object is null stopping me to proceed.

This is my core element,

```
<polymer-element name="get-employees" attributes="employeeList">
    <template>      
        <core-ajax id="ajax" auto
               url="https://localhost:8443/GetEmployees"
               method='POST'
               headers='{"X-Token":"4517612052875154027"}'
               handleAs='xml'
               contentType="application/xml"
               response= "{{resp}}"
               on-core-complete="{{success}}"
               on-core-error="{{errorF}}"
               body='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><GetEmployees xmlns="http://www.22s.net/emp/1.0"><<Employees><Employee><EmployeeNo/><TitleCode/><Initials/>   <GivenNames/><Surname/></GetEmployees>'>
        </core-ajax>
        <template repeat="{{employee in resp | nodeList('Employee') }}" id="tem">
          <div class="empcard" flex>
            <div>{{employee || nodeText('GivenNames')}}</div>
          </div>
        </template>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer('get-employees', {
        errorF: function(){
            console.log('Error occured');
        },
        success: function(event, detail, sender){
            console.log(event);
        },          
        nodeList: function(element, name) {
            var arr;
            arr =  element ?
              [].slice.call(element.querySelectorAll(name)) : ['No Employees for the given query'];
            return arr;
        },
        nodeText: function(element, name) {
            return element.querySelector(name).innerHTML;

        }
    });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

The XML returned in in following format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetEmployeesResponse xmlns="http://www.22s.net/emp/1.0">
<APIResponseStatus>
    <Code>OK</Code>
</APIResponseStatus>
<Employees>
    <Employee>
        <EmployeeNo>ISH001</EmployeeNo>
        <GivenNames>Omid</GivenNames>
        <Initials>OR</Initials>
        <Surname>KORDESTANI</Surname>
        <TitleCode>Mr</TitleCode>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <EmployeeNo>ISH002</EmployeeNo>
        <GivenNames>Gary</GivenNames>
        <Initials>GR</Initials>
        <Surname>PARANTE</Surname>
        <TitleCode>Mr</TitleCode>
    </Employee>     
</Employees>
</GetEmployeesResponse>
```

When I debug *event* or *detail* objects in success method does not carry the return XML or *resp* object.  The *element* parameter for *nodeList* function also returns "No Employees...." message.

Can someone please let me know where I have messed up. I have tried otherthings but none has succeeded so far.

**EDIT**: 
When I save the response XML in a server file and made a GET request to it the page shows,

```
[Object Element]  
[Object Element]
[Object Element]
```

via the template. Its the exact same response XML. I am confused!!!!!!!!

Thanks in advance,
Ish

Comment: It looks like you can GET the XML ok, so I'm wondering if your server is properly returning it from the POST. Instead of using core-ajax, can you just write a vanilla XHR and see if you receive the expected response from POST?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. Make sure that server returns proper `Header` with

```
'Content-Type: application/xml'
```

and/or the extension of a file returned is `.xml`. I tested it on the same file twice using simple python `SimpleHTTPServer`: whether the file had an extension `.xml` `core-ajax` worked as expected; changing an extension to `.kml` resulted in `null` response as by component.

Hope it helps.